# Frequency estimation on chaotic waveform

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, stft

The target signal is generated by the following analytically solvable hybrid chaotic oscillator

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\ddot{u}  - 2\beta \dot{u}  +(\omega^2+\beta^2)(u-s)=0
\end{equation}

where

- $\omega$ determines the symbol period as $T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega}$.
- $\beta \in (0,T^{-1}\ln 2)$ affects the fluctuating amplitude.
- $s \in{\pm 1}$ is the random bipolar symbol sequence driving the system.

Its typical continuous waveform $u(t)$ for $f=100 \, \mathrm{Hz}$ is as follows:

[image]

I am interested in estimating the basis frequency $f$ of the signal. However, the amplitude spectrum of $u(t)$ has no obvious feature that can be used to estimate the frequency. Hence, I calculate

$$z(t) = |u(t)| - 1$$

The amplitude spectrum of $z(t)$ is as follows

[image]

Obviously, we can see a spike at $f = 100 \, \mathrm{Hz}$. But it is hard to calculate the accurate expression of $z(f)$ since $u(t)$ is a kind of non-stationary signal.

The STFT time-frequency spectrum is shown below

[image]

As shown in the STFT results, in some time intervals, no obvious frequency component can be found. However, in the part of approximately periodic waveform, the frequency component at $f = 100 \, \mathrm{Hz}$ is strong.

Is there any theory that can support my method of frequency estimation from the FFT of the whole $z(t)$?

---

Here is the MATLAB code for generating the chaotic waveform from an analytical expression (not provided above) and my current experiments on frequency estimation.

````
clear;close all;

finit = 100;%set frequency
% finit =2000;
% finit =2;
om=2*pi*finit;
be=om/(2*pi)*log(2)-0.01*rand(1,1);
T = 2*pi/om; %Period
N=100;% number of symbol
tall = N*T;%total time
h=T*0.01;%time step
t=0:h:tall-h;
ut=zeros(1,length(t));
u_in = 2*rand(1)-1;
% u_in =0.99;
for i=1:N
    if u_in>=0
        s_in = 1;
    else
        s_in = -1;
    end
    t_f = (i-1)*T:h:i*T-h;  %Time of each frame
    n_f = (i-1)*length(t_f)+1:i*length(t_f);
    ut(n_f)=s_in+(u_in-s_in)*exp(be*(t_f+(1-i)*T)).*...
           (cos(om*t_f)-be/om*sin(om*t_f));
    u_in=s_in+(u_in-s_in)*exp(be*T)*cos(om*i*T);
end

figure
plot(t, ut)
xlabel('Time t/s');
title('u(t)')

y = abs(ut) - 1; % Observed signal

%% FFT spectrum
L = length(ut);
Ts_v = t./(0:L-1);
Fs = ceil(1/Ts_v(2));
deltaf= 0.1;
NFFT = floor(Fs/deltaf);
fs = Fs;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,floor(NFFT/2+1));
Y = fft(y,NFFT)/L;
Yabs = 20*log10(abs(Y(1:floor(NFFT/2+1))));
figure;
plot(f,Yabs);
xlim([0,max(f)/4]);
ylim([-100,0]);
xlabel('Frequency f/Hz');
title('FFT Spectrum');
%%  Wavelet Transfrom Time-Frequency spectrum
wavename='cmor3-3';
totalscal=256*2;
Fc=centfrq(wavename); 
c=2*Fc*totalscal;
scals=c./(1:totalscal);
f=scal2frq(scals,wavename,1/fs); 
coefs=cwt(y ,scals,wavename); 


figure;
subplot(211)
plot(t,y,'linewidth',1)
xlim([0 1])
ylim([-1.5 1.5])
subplot(212)
imagesc(t,f,abs(coefs));
set(gca,'YDir','normal')
ylim([0 200]);
% colorbar;
xlabel('Time t/s');
ylabel('Frequency f/Hz');
title('Wavelet Time-Frequency Spectrum');
%% STFT Time-Frequency spectrum
window_len = 10*2*pi/om/h;
noverlap = 50;
nfft = NFFT;
[~,F,T,P]=spectrogram(y,hamming(window_len),noverlap,nfft,fs);


figure;
subplot(211)
plot(t,y,'linewidth',1)
xlabel('Time t/s');
title('|u(t)|-1')
xlim([0 1])
ylim([-1.5 1.5])
subplot(212)
surf(T,F,abs(P),'edgecolor','none')
axis tight;
view(0,90)
ylim([0 200]);
xlabel('Time t/s');
ylabel('Frequency f/Hz');
title('STFT Time-Frequency Spectrum');
```
````

Comment: This looks really interesting.  My first inclination would to take the first derivate (technically an approximation thereof), then look at zero crossings.  If you want it to show up in a DFT, chop all the peaks off (of the derivative) at a constant height making in essence a square wave.  The DFT will then give you clear peaks and the fundamental, the third, the fifth, and a little of the seventh harmonics.    I'll double back tomorrow, see what you have done.

Comment: Do you have the code to  generate that typical waveform somewhere? I'd like to play around with it a bit! Also, how did you calculate that amplitude spectrum? Gotta be a little careful here, if this process is not weak-sense stationary, then the Wiener-Khinchin Theorem's requirements are not fulfilled, and you need to calculate the PSD as Fourier Transform(Autocorrelation(Process))) (and not estimate directly as Fourier Transform(realization)²)

Comment: Thanks you for kind suggestions. I will think about it. The MATLAB code to generate the waveform is provieded in the edited part.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stab.

Start with:

$$ \ddot{u}  - 2\beta \dot{u}  +(\omega^2+\beta^2)(u-s)=0 $$

Take the derivative:

$$ \dddot{u}  - 2\beta \ddot{u}  +(\omega^2+\beta^2)(\dot{u}-\dot{s})=0 $$

Now, $ \dot{s} = 0 $ Wherever it is defined.  So:

$$ \dddot{u}  - 2\beta \ddot{u}  +(\omega^2+\beta^2)(\dot{u})=0 $$

Let $ v = \dot{u} $, and you get

$$ \ddot{v}  - 2\beta \dot{v}  +(\omega^2+\beta^2)v=0 $$

Which is an ordinary second degree linear differential equation.  v will have the same frequency as u.

The most basic (good) differential approximation is:

$$ d[n] = \frac{u[n+1]-u[n-1]}{2} $$

So run that over your data and see what you get and please add a chart to your question with the results.

I think you may best solve this one by analyzing the zero crossing of those results.  The transitions are going to cause weirdness as your system "falls" towards the new equilibrium.

---

Followup:

A more traditional approach perhaps.

$$ \ddot{u}  - 2\beta \dot{u}  +(\omega^2+\beta^2)(u-s)=0 $$

Your homogenuous equation is:

$$ \ddot{u}  - 2\beta \dot{u}  +(\omega^2+\beta^2) u=0 $$

with solutions:

$$ u_h = \left[ C_1 \cos( \omega t ) + C_2 \sin( \omega t ) \right] e ^ { \beta t } $$

And your particular equation is:

$$ \ddot{u}  - 2\beta \dot{u}  +(\omega^2+\beta^2) s=0 $$

Assume:

$$ u = a t^2 + b t + c $$

$$ \dot{u} =  2 a t + b $$

$$ \ddot{u} =  2 a  $$

$$ (2a)  - 2\beta ( 2 a t + b )  + (\omega^2+\beta^2) s=0 $$

$$ (2 - 4 \beta  t)  a  - 2\beta  b   + (\omega^2+\beta^2) s=0 $$

$$ a = 0 $$

$$ b = \frac{\omega^2+\beta^2}{2\beta} \cdot s $$

So :

$$ u_p = \left( \frac{\omega^2+\beta^2}{2\beta} \cdot s \right) t $$

For any range of consistent $s$ you now have your general and particular solutions.

Therefore you should only need five points to solve for your five unknowns:  $ \omega, \beta, C_1, C_2,$ and $ c $.

With noise, that goes out the window.  If you take the second derivative, your particular solution will be squashed completely.  Then you should only have to worry about the $s$ transition points.

Line crossings will give you $\omega$, and the envelope will give you $\beta$.